# Postfix virtual domain address not working

Tags: postfix-mta

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and postfix installed. Emailing is working great with the real hostname and suffix, but receiving mail from outside (like from gmail) to virtual adresses wont work.

Real hostname mailbox (user1@domain.name.net) receives email ok from outside.

Also sending mail inside server to virtual address works ok.

```
echo "test message" | mailx -s 'test subject' user1@mailserver.com
```

Sending email from gmail gives an "Relay access" error.

```
Mail Delivery Subsystem: <mailer-daemon@googlemail.com>
Subject: Delivery Status notification (Failure)
554 5.7.1 <user1@mailserver.com>: Relay access denied
```

server hostname

```
domain.name.net
```

mx records

```
dig mailserver.com mx

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> mailserver.com mx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35230
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mailserver.com.                      IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mailserver.com.               3600    IN      MX      10 mail.vpshost.com.

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: su syys 20 16:45:47 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destinati>
myhostname = domain.name.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = domain.name.net, localhost.name.net, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_dest>
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_domains = mailserver.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

/etc/postfix/virtual

```
### mailserver.com aliases ###

virtual-alias.domain    anything
info@mailserver.com     user1
user1@mailserver.com    user1
```

/etc/aliases

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    user1
user.name:     user1
```

Comment: There is a tutorial series that goes through the setting up of virtual mail servers using Postfix here: https://blog.terresquall.com/2022/01/setting-up-a-virtual-postfix-mail-server-part-1/

It is a 3-part series that goes through how to receive emails, send emails and set up mail policies so that your emails don't fall into Junk / Spam.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved now. We didnt have any MX records on VPS provider side. After adding correct ip+domain records everything works.